# Angular. Удаление элемента с корзины LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, localstorage, корзина

Сделал корзину на сайте, через *ngFor="let item of product; let productId = index"
добавляю новые div с товаром.
Кнопка есть в каждом товаре "удалить" ей задано:

basket.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class BasketService {
  basket = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  basketCount = new BehaviorSubject(0);

  constructor() {
    this.setToLocalStorage();
  }

  setToBasket(product): void {
    this.setToLocalStorage(product);
    console.log(product);
  }

  private setToLocalStorage(product?): void {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("basket")) {
      localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify([]));
    } else {
      this.basket.next(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket")));
      this.basketCount.next(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket")).length);
    }
    if (!product) {
      return
    }

    const basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket"));
    basket.push(product);
    localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(basket));
    this.basket.next(basket);
    this.basketCount.next(basket.length)
  }
}
```

basket.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {BasketService} from 'src/app/core/services/basket/basket.service';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {takeUntil} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-basket',
  templateUrl: './basket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./basket.component.css']
})
export class BasketComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  basketList;
  product;
  basket;
  productIndex: number;
  id: number;

  private unsubscribe = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private basketService: BasketService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getBasketList();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe.next();
    this.unsubscribe.complete();
  }

  getBasketList(): void {
    this.basketService.basket.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.product = data;
        });
  }

  clearBasket(): void {
    localStorage.clear()
  }

  // deleteBasketItem(): void {
  //   var basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket"));

  //   this.basket.splice("this.basket", JSON.stringify(this.id), 1);
  //   localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(basket));
  //   console.log(this.id)
  // }

  deleteBasketItem(productId) {
    var basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket"));
    var index = basket.findIndex(x => x == productId);
    basket.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(basket));
  }
}
```

basket.component.html:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="col-12 title">
    <h2>Корзина</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 clear">
    <button class="buttonDeleteAll" (click)="clearBasket()">Очистить</button>
  </div>

  <div class="mt-4 basketItem" *ngFor="let item of product; let productId = index">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center pictureOfItemDiv">
        <img [src]="item.picture" class="mt-1 itemPictureOnBasket" alt="...">
      </div>

      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="col-12 row mt-3 headerOfItem">
          <div class="col-5">
            <p>Название</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <p>Код товара</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>Цена</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>К-во</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 row mt-3 footerOfItem">
          <div class="col-5">
            <p>{{item.name}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <p>{{item.id}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>{{item.price}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>{{item.count}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 d-flex align-items-center">
        <button class="deleteItemButton" (click)="deleteBasketItem(productId)" value="{{productId}}">
            <span class="text-danger material-icons md-40 deleteItemIcon">
                delete
            </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 mt-5 d-flex justify-content-end">
    <div>
      <p><b>Сумма: ---</b></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 mt-5 ">
    <button class="buttonDeleteAll" (click)="clearBasket()">
            Подтвердить
        </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Понимаю что productId не так считывается. Подскажите, как правильно реализовать это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/localstorage-stackoverflow

```html
<div class="mt-4 basketItem" *ngFor="let item of product; let i = index">
  <!--  i - это индекс элемента массива, id - это идентификатор продукта -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center pictureOfItemDiv">
      <img [src]="item.picture" class="mt-1 itemPictureOnBasket" alt="...">
    </div>

    <div class="col-8" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="col-12 row mt-3 headerOfItem">
        <div class="col-5" style=" margin-right:20px">
          <p>Название</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5" style=" margin-right:20px">
          <p>ID</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <p>Код товара</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <p>Цена</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <p>К-во</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 row mt-3 footerOfItem">
        <div class="col-5">
          <p>{{item.id}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
          <p>{{item.name}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <p>{{item.code}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <p>{{item.price}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <p>{{item.count}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 d-flex align-items-center">
      <!--  зачем в button нужно value? -->
      <button class="deleteItemButton" (click)="deleteBasketItem(item.id)" value="{{item.id}}">
          <span class="text-danger material-icons md-40 deleteItemIcon">
              delete
          </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
...
clearBasket(): void {
    localStorage.clear()
    this.product = [] // очищаем this.product тоже
}

deleteBasketItem(productId: number) {
    this.basketService.removeFromLocalstorage(productId);

    var index = this.product.findIndex(x => x.id == productId);
    this.product.splice(index, 1); // удаляем с this.product тоже
}
```

basket.service:

```
basket = new BehaviorSubject([]);
products = [];

basketCount = new BehaviorSubject(0);

constructor() {
    this.fillBasket();
}

fillBasket() {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("basket"))
        return

    var basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket"));
    this.products = basket;
    this.basket.next(this.products );
}

setToBasket(product): void {
    this.products.push(product);
    this.basket.next(this.products);
    this.setToLocalStorage(product);
}

private setToLocalStorage(product?): void {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("basket")) {
        localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify([]));
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(this.products));
        this.basket.next(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket")));
    }
    if (!product) {
        return
    }
}

removeFromLocalstorage(id) {
    var basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket"));
    var index = basket.findIndex(x => x.id == id);

    basket.splice(index, 1); // удаляем с локалсторедж
    localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(basket));
}
```

Comment: В таком случае у меня удаляет только последний элемент, не смотря что нажму на другие, возможно можно через array.filter решить?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста полностью код с файлов .ts и .html, так сложно сказать

Comment: отредактировал, добавил с service, ts, html

Comment: У вас ошибка в следующем: старайтесь всегда использовать ID продукта, а не его индекс. В html у вас индекс подписан productId, но по факту это индекс элемента массива:  *ngFor="let item of product; let i = index" - так должно быть. И дальше в функциях используйте именно ID продукта. Еще ошибка - называть массив продуктов product; правильно - products. И еще ошибка - вы удаляете с локалсторедж, но не удаляете продукты с переменной this.product

Comment: Буду пробовать исправлять) Просто это первый проект, только начал изучать программирование

Comment: ** Немного еще поправила** Отличное начало! Удачи :)

Comment: большое спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Вы создали сервис чтобы получать данные - это хорошее решение, но при этом удаляете и очищаете через компонент - это плохое решение.

Ваш метод `deleteBasketItem` получает на вход `index` внутри массива `baskets`, но ищите вы его неверно. У вас в принципе уже есть индекс и дополнительно искать ничего не нужно.
Как вариант можете воспользоваться функцией [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) или [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
// удалить только один элемент (исходный массив изменится)
basket.splice(productId, 1)
// или отфильтровать и создать новый массив
basket = basket.filter((item,index) => index === productId);
```